# Php array нестандартная сортировка

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить такую задачку:

Есть некий ассоциативный массив вида:

```
[key_1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
    )
[key_2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
    )
[key_3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
    )
[key_4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
    )
[key_5] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
    )
[key_6] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
    )
[key_7] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
    )
```

Мне надо отсортировать этот массив по значению внутри каждого массива в такой вид, при этом сохранив ключи:

```
[key_1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
    )
[key_2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
    )
[key_5] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
    )   
[key_3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
    )
[key_6] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
    )   
[key_4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
    )
```

То есть получился массив, где значение ключей чередуются: 0|1|0|1|0|1...
Всю голову сломал не пойму как это сделать.

Comment: Почему на входе 7 элементов, а на выходе только 4? Предоставьте более подробное описание, что вы хотите получить.

Comment: А какова последовательно ключей - без разницы? Т.е. если будут ключи например: 1 4 5 3 6 2 - это норм? или что как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала собираем массив ключей, а затем пробегаем по нему двумя указателями:

```php
$a = [
'key_1' => ['0' => 0],
'key_2' => ['0' => 1],
'key_3' => ['0' => 1],
'key_4' => ['0' => 1],
'key_5' => ['0' => 0],
'key_6' => ['0' => 0],
'key_7' => ['0' => 1],
];

$keys = array_keys($a);

$b = [];
$i = $j = $v = 0;
$count = count($a);
while ($i < $count && $j < $count && $z++ < 100) {
    while ($i < $count && $a[$keys[$i]][0] != $v /* 0 */) {
        $i++;
    }
    if ($i < $count) {
        $b[$keys[$i]] = $a[$keys[$i]];
        $i++;
        $v = 1 - $v;
    }

    while ($j < $count && $a[$keys[$j]][0] != $v /* 1 */) {
        $j++;
    }
    if ($j < $count) {
        $b[$keys[$j]] = $a[$keys[$j]];
        $j++;
        $v = 1 - $v;
    }
}
var_export($b);
```

Если же в массиве преобладание какого-то значения, а отбрасывать лишние значения нельзя, то не используем переменную $v, а сравниваем непосредственно с 0 и 1.

$z - техническая переменная от случайного зацикливания.

Answer (score 2):

Если последовательность ключей не имеет значения, то самый простой вариант "в лоб", сделать так:

1. Вначале применить сортировку в принципе, по значениям, чтобы был массив вида `[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1]`. Здесь упрощённая схема, без упоминания ключей, чтобы было понятно.

   Тут можно применить функцию [uasort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php)
2. Пробежаться циклом по этому массиву и собирать в новый массив по очереди вытаскавая по два значения: один с начала и один с конца, затем один второй элемент с начала и один второй элемент с конца, и т.д..... Можно двигаться попарно так: один элемент с начала и первый элемент от середины, второй элемент с начала и второй элемент с середины, и т.д.

   Для цикла может понадобиться:

   1. Пробегание от начала до середины массива (т.е. до `$i < count($arr) / 2` ... В случае если число элементов нечётное то необходимо среднее число округлить в большую сторону и иметь проверку впоследствии на этот нюанс)
   2. [array_slice](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) для срезания элемента из отсортированного массива
   3. Умение формировать динамически ключ массива, например `$key1 = 'key_' . ($i + 1);`
   4. [current](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.current.php) для того, чтобы извлечь значение массива без ключа

Шаг №2 можно делать по-всякому и можно найти проще варианты. Но суть остаётся - вначале отсортировать, потом распихать.

Можно сделать изначально простой ассоциативный массив в виде `key => value`, для упрощения всех манипуляций (также подойдут для этих целей и [Map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ds-map.map.php))